# string length failing in Azure using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, azure

I having issues with SQL Azure, the following LINQ with EF code works fine if the database is SQL Server 2012

```
var userLength = users.Select(n => new { n.FirstName.Length });
```

But, if I point it to an Azure database and I get

> "base = {"The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."}"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the databases contain same data?

Maybe one of users has no FirstName set in Azure database?

I guess it's when you iterate over usersLength that you receive this Exception? Is it thrown on first iteration or maybe later?

Here's what I think is happenning (I'm using LINQ to Objects here)

[image]

You can edit it like this to make it return 0 for null elements (FirstNames):

[image]

You can download those two code snippets if you have LinqPad here (they will be automatically opened in LinqPad):

http://share.linqpad.net/2pfjqf.linq

http://share.linqpad.net/vp96kf.linq